# Mousemove event added in mousedown event keeps firing while the mouse is not moving

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, mousemove, mousedown

I am working at a simple sequence of mouse event listeners in the form of "mousedown" -> "mousemove" -> "mouseup". What I am trying to do is add two event listeners for `mousemove` and `mouseup` when the `mousedown` event fires.

My code looks like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("mousedown",stagesContainerGrabMouseDownHandler)

function stagesContainerGrabMouseDownHandler(ev){
      document.addEventListener("mousemove",stagesContainerGrabMouseMoveHandler);
        document.addEventListener("mouseup",stagesContainerGrabMouseUpHandler)
}

function stagesContainerGrabMouseMoveHandler(ev){
        console.log(12)
}

function stagesContainerGrabMouseUpHandler(ev){
    document.removeEventListener("mousemove",stagesContainerGrabMouseMoveHandler);
    document.removeEventListener("mouseup",stagesContainerGrabMouseUpHandler);
}
```

The problem is that when I keep the mouse pressed, the mousemove event keeps firing even if my mouse stays still. I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found the culprit. I didn't even think to look there. I am running a script in the background with AutoHotKey and for some reason it seems that it interacts with my page. Turning it off solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the issue must be coming from somewhere else — perhaps other code or the mouse you're using.

I tested the code you included in a DevTools Console (both in Edge and Chrome) and the event doesn't fire when I keep my mouse pressed down and still.

Comment: It is about keeping the mouse still while having it pressed down.

Comment: I clarified my post. I conducted my testing with the mouse pressed down and still. If I simply press down without movement, the console only logs "12" once.

Comment: Strange. no matter what browser I use, this code causes 12 to keep being console logged if I press and hold anywhere on the document.

Comment: Yeap. Even on here or JSFiddle I get this strange problem.